# C# unassigned array but can assign it anything?

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I am having a bit of trouble getting this c# code to work I can get it to work if I use the console.write that I have commented out but I can get those same results stored in this array for me to use in a different section of my program.

```
FileInfo[] selectionFileOrder;
     for (int index = 0; index < dateAllOrder.Length; index++)
     {
          if (dateAllOrder[index].LastAccessTime.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
          {
               int i = 0;
               i++;
               selectionFileOrder[i] = dateAllOrder[index];
               // Console.Write("{1}. {0}", dateAllOrder[index].Name, index);
               // Console.Write(" ({0}) ", dateAllOrder[index].Length);
               Console.WriteLine();
          }
      }
```

I have looked at google and can't seem to find any answers to my issue I know that it is the variable selectionFileOrder that is unsigned but I don't have anything to assign to it. Any fresh ideas would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize the array:

```
FileInfo[] selectionFileOrder = new FileInfo[dateAllOrder.Length];
```

or better, use a List:

```
IList<FileInfo> selectionFileOrder = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach(FileInfo item in dateAllOrder)
{
     if (item.LastAccessTime.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
     {
          selectionFileOrder.Add(item);
          // Console.Write("{1}. {0}", dateAllOrder[index].Name, index);
          // Console.Write(" ({0}) ", dateAllOrder[index].Length);
          Console.WriteLine();
     }
}
```

Or best, use LINQ!

Answer (score 3):

I would use LINQ to do this:

```
FileInfo[] selectionFileOrder = dateAllOrder.Where(
    d => d.LastAccessTime.Month == DateTime.Today.Month).ToArray();
```

Since it looks like you don't know how big the array needs to be ahead of time, I would recommend a list like so:

```
 var selectionFileOrder = new List<FileInfo>();
 for (int index = 0; index < dateAllOrder.Length; index++)
 {
      if (dateAllOrder[index].LastAccessTime.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
      {
           selectionFileOrder.Add(dateAllOrder[index]);
      }
  }
```

You can assign the list to an array later if you like

```
FileInfo[] array = selectionFileOrder.ToArray();
```

Also it looked like you had a bug where `i` would always be 1, which isn't what you want I think.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list rather than an array to allow you to increase the size of selectionFileOrder dynamically like so:

```
 var selectionFileOrder = new List<FileInfo>();
 for (int index = 0; index < dateAllOrder.Length; index++)
 {
      if (dateAllOrder[index].LastAccessTime.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
      {
           selectionFileOrder.Add(dateAllOrder[index]);
      }
  }
```

Or alternatively, just use LINQ:

```
var selectionFileOrder = dateAllOrder.Where(o => o.LastAccessTime.Month == DateTime.Now.Month).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put an array in the variable:

```
selectionFileOrder = new FileInfo[942];
```

*Make sure to change `942` to a meaningful relevant number*

Comment: where did you get the magic number 942? This is a horrible way to guide young programmers.

Comment: I have tried this and it works kind of but i now get an error on the other bit of my code because i have null values

Comment: @vidstige: It's a number strange enough to convince new programmers to think about it (I hope)

Comment: @SLaks kids do as their parents. New programers do as the gurus. Please be more responisble.

Comment: @SLaks. It's pretty obvious he needs to be using a list of some description. Telling him to use an array really isn't a good idea - especially since you have such a high rep as he's likely to follow your example fairly blindly thinking you're doing it exactly as it should be done.